# What third-party games have been included with Macs at some point?

Tags: mac, software, games, history, third-party

To phrase it differently: Over the years, Mac computers have come with various pieces of software not developed by Apple, many of which are games, such as Marble Blast Gold, Bugdom, and the Big Bang Board Games suite.

After much searching, I've been unable to find a comprehensive list anywhere. What non-Apple games have been preinstalled or bundled with computers running Mac OS, and when were they included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this list covers all models from 2000–present, and *most* models from 1995–2000. However, this list is still **incomplete**. Please contribute if you know of anything wrong or missing!

In cases where software could either be considered a "game" or not (e.g. Kid Pix), I've generally erred on the side of inclusion.

<sup>†</sup> indicates bundled software that was not preinstalled. <sup>‡</sup> indicates software which I have not yet determined whether was preinstalled or bundled.

Sources indicated by “mA” for madeApple links, ↗︎ arrows for other links, and “MT” for information available via [Mactracker](https://mactracker.ca/).

- [Spin Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClockWerx)<sup>‡</sup>, [Super Maze Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisto_Corporation)<sup>‡</sup>, [Eric's Solitaire Sampler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric%27s_Ultimate_Solitaire)<sup>‡</sup> — 1995

  - PowerBook 190<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19981202202300/http://product.info.apple.com:80/pr/press.releases/1995/q4/950828.pr.rel.pbs.html)</sup>
  - PowerBook 2300<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19981202202300/http://product.info.apple.com:80/pr/press.releases/1995/q4/950828.pr.rel.pbs.html)</sup>
  - PowerBook 5300<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19981202202300/http://product.info.apple.com:80/pr/press.releases/1995/q4/950828.pr.rel.pbs.html)</sup>
- [DOGZ Adoption Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petz), [Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_(1995_video_game))<sup>†</sup>, [Thinkin' Things Collection 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinkin%27_Things)<sup>†</sup>, [Club KidSoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_Kidsoft)<sup>†</sup>, [The Amazing Writing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Broderbund_products)<sup>†</sup>

  - Performa 6400/6410/6420<sup>[↗︎](http://www.1000bit.it/ad/bro/apple/ApplePerforma6400-180.pdf) [↗︎](https://archive.org/details/ads_AvidCin)</sup>
- [Weekend Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangea_Software)<sup>†</sup>, [Thinkin' Things Collection 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinkin%27_Things)<sup>†</sup>, [KidPix Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kid_Pix#Kid_Pix_Studio)<sup>†</sup>, [Descent II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_II)<sup>†</sup>, [Where in the USA is Carmen Sandiego?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_in_the_U.S.A._Is_Carmen_Sandiego%3F_(1996_video_game))<sup>†</sup>, [VR Soccer 96 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VR_Soccer)<sup>†</sup>, [Virtual Pool 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Pool_(video_game))<sup>†</sup>, [Mechwarrior 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MechWarrior_2:_31st_Century_Combat)<sup>†</sup>, [The Amazing Writing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Broderbund_products)<sup>†</sup> — 1997

  - Power Macintosh 6500 (except Education Edition)<sup>[↗︎](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/success-with-the-power-macintosh-4400.2077767/post-25228063) [↗︎](https://issuu.com/dougalder/docs/1997-12_the_computer_paper_bc-ocr/68)</sup>
- [Virtual Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Pool_(video_game))<sup>‡</sup> — 1997

  - PowerBook 3400<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19981202091413/http://product.info.apple.com/pr/press.releases/1997/q2/970217.pr.rel.pb3400.html)</sup>
- [Nanosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosaur) — 1999–2001

  - iBook (1999–2000 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/ibook/) [2](https://madeapple.com/ibook-special-edition/) [3](https://madeapple.com/ibook-with-firewire/) [4](https://madeapple.com/ibook-special-edition-with-firewire/)]</sup>
  - iBook (Dual USB)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/ibook-with-dual-usb/)</sup>
  - iMac (5 Flavors)<sup>[↗︎](https://archive.org/details/ads_L03538C_US_iMac_DS)</sup>
  - iMac/iMac DV/iMac DV+/iMac DV SE<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19991013104443/http://apple.com:80/imac/software.html)</sup>
  - iMac (all 2001 models)<sup>[↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/it/Images/imacfeb.pdf) [↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/es/Images/imac_datasheet.pdf) [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-early-2001/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-early-2001/) [3](https://madeapple.com/imac-mid-2001/) [4](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-mid-2001/)]</sup>
  - Power Mac G4 Cube<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/power-mac-g4-cube/)</sup>
- Kid Pix Studio Deluxe

  - iMac/iMac DV/iMac DV SE <sup>[↗︎](https://archive.org/details/ads_L04649A_US_iMac_DV_DS)</sup>
- [Bugdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugdom) — 1999–2001

  - iBook (1999–2000 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/ibook/) [2](https://madeapple.com/ibook-special-edition/) [3](https://madeapple.com/ibook-with-firewire/) [4](https://madeapple.com/ibook-special-edition-with-firewire/)]</sup>
  - iBook (Dual USB)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/ibook-with-dual-usb/)</sup>
  - iMac/iMac DV/iMac DV+/iMac DV SE<sup>[↗︎](https://web.archive.org/web/19991013104443/http://apple.com:80/imac/software.html)</sup>
  - iMac (all 2001 models)<sup>[↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/it/Images/imacfeb.pdf) [↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/es/Images/imac_datasheet.pdf) [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-early-2001/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-early-2001/) [3](https://madeapple.com/imac-mid-2001/) [4](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-mid-2001/)]</sup>
  - Power Mac G4 Cube<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/power-mac-g4-cube/)</sup>
- [Cro-Mag Rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cro-Mag_Rally) — 2000–Mid 2001

  - iBook (Dual USB)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/ibook-with-dual-usb/)</sup>
  - iMac (all 2001 models)<sup>[↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/it/Images/imacfeb.pdf) [↗︎](https://store.apple.com/Catalog/es/Images/imac_datasheet.pdf) [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-early-2001/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-early-2001/) [3](https://madeapple.com/imac-mid-2001/) [4](https://madeapple.com/imac-special-edition-mid-2001/)]</sup>
  - Power Mac G4 Cube<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/power-mac-g4-cube/)</sup>
- [Otto Matic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Matic) — Late 2001–2004

  - iBook (Late 2001)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/ibook-late-2001/)</sup>
  - iBook (14.1")<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch/)</sup>
  - iBook (all May 2002–2004 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/ibook-mid-2002/) [2](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-mid-2002/) [3](https://madeapple.com/ibook-late-2002/) [4](https://madeapple.com/ibook-opaque-white-late-2002/) [5](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-late-2002/) [6](https://madeapple.com/ibook-early-2003/) [7](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-early-2003/) [8](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch/) [9](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch/) [10](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch-early-2004/) [11](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch-early-2004/) [12](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch-late-2004/) [13](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch-late-2004/)]</sup>
  - iMac (all 2002–2004 models)<sup>[mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-with-flat-panel-display/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-with-flat-panel-display/) [3](https://madeapple.com/imac-15-inch-early-2003/) [4](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-early-2003/) [5](https://madeapple.com/imac-15-inch-late-2003/) [6](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-late-2003/) [7](https://madeapple.com/imac-20-inch-late-2003/) [8](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-17-inch/) [9](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-20-inch/)]</sup>
  - eMac (all 2002–2003 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/emac/) [2](https://madeapple.com/emac-with-ati-graphics/) [3](https://madeapple.com/emac-late-2003/)]</sup>
- [Deimos Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Rising) — 2002–2004

  - iBook (all May 2002–2004 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/ibook-mid-2002/) [2](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-mid-2002/) [3](https://madeapple.com/ibook-late-2002/) [4](https://madeapple.com/ibook-opaque-white-late-2002/) [5](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-late-2002/) [6](https://madeapple.com/ibook-early-2003/) [7](https://madeapple.com/ibook-14-1-inch-early-2003/) [8](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch/) [9](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch/) [10](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch-early-2004/) [11](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch-early-2004/) [12](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch-late-2004/) [13](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch-late-2004/)]</sup>
  - iMac (all 2002–2004 models)<sup>[mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-with-flat-panel-display/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-with-flat-panel-display/) [3](https://madeapple.com/imac-15-inch-early-2003/) [4](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-early-2003/) [5](https://madeapple.com/imac-15-inch-late-2003/) [6](https://madeapple.com/imac-17-inch-late-2003/) [7](https://madeapple.com/imac-20-inch-late-2003/) [8](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-17-inch/) [9](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-20-inch/)]</sup>
  - eMac (all 2002–2003 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/emac/) [2](https://madeapple.com/emac-with-ati-graphics/) [3](https://madeapple.com/emac-late-2003/)]</sup>
  - eMac (USB 2.0)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/emac-early-2004/)</sup>
- [Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hawk%27s_Pro_Skater_4) — 2004

  - eMac (USB 2.0)<sup>MT</sup>
- [Nanosaur 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosaur_2:_Hatchling), [Marble Blast Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble_Blast_Gold) — 2005

  - iBook G4 (Mid 2005)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-12-inch-2005/) [2](https://madeapple.com/ibook-g4-14-1-inch-2005/)]</sup>
  - iMac G5 (iSight)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-17-inch-late-2005/) [2](https://madeapple.com/imac-g5-20-inch-late-2005/)]</sup>
  - eMac (2005)<sup>MT*</sup>
  - Mac Mini<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/mac-mini/)</sup>
  - Mac Mini (Late 2005)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/mac-mini-late-2005/)</sup>
- [Big Bang Board Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeverse_Inc.) — 2006–2007

  - iMac (all Sept 2006 models)<sup>MT</sup>
  - Mac Mini (Early 2006)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/mac-mini-early-2006/)</sup>
  - Mac Mini (Late 2006)<sup>MT [mA](https://madeapple.com/mac-mini-late-2006/)</sup>
  - MacBook (all 2006–Mid 2007 models)<sup>MT [mA [1](https://madeapple.com/macbook-13-inch/) [2](https://madeapple.com/macbook-13-inch-late-2006/) [3](https://madeapple.com/macbook-13-inch-mid-2007/)]</sup>

*madeApple [disagrees](https://madeapple.com/emac-2005/), but I believe it's more likely that Mactracker is correct, given the years involved.

(Formatting note: models were combined if there were at least three computers from the same product line, and which did not differ in their included games. Games were combined if there was no difference in what models came with them.)

Comment: Cro-Mag Rally! Man, that brings back memories. There were a few settings in the physics of Cro-Mag which when configured the right way, would let your 'car' fly around and actually go into non-player parts of the game.

Comment: There was Kid’s Studio or KidPix which was a drawing program with animations and sounds. iMac G3 350Mhz had it. (Slot loader around 1999)

Comment: I don't know what dates would apply or what other machines had it, but the Power Macintosh 6500 was bundled with Descent II and MechWarrior 2. I couldn't find a good citation to back up my memory but [here's a random forum post that mentions it](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=39993&start=8640).

Comment: what about chess

Comment: @theonlygusti The Chess application is from Apple, i.e. first-party, not third-party.